# Git uncertainty - customized, but able to pull in upstream changes?

Tags: git

I have [phabricator](http://phabricator.org) set up. Being relatively green with git, what's the sane/proper way to make sure that I can have my own configuration files (and possibly some hacks in other files) coexist with what comes in from upstream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your changes on a separate branch.  Let's assume that you track the upstream changes in a `vendor` branch, and you work on the `master` branch.  Then you would do something like this to bring in upstream updates:

- Switch to the `vendor` branch:

  ```
  git checkout vendor
  ```
- Pull in the new updates:

  ```
  git pull
  ```
- Switch to your `master` branch:

  ```
  git checkout master
  ```
- Merge the changes:

  ```
  git merge vendor
  ```
- Fix conflicts and commit.

Going into a little more detail...assume your upstream repository is
`http://github.com/spiffy/project.git`, and you want to track the `master`
branch.  Clone the repository:

```
$ git clone http://github.com/spiffy/project.git
$ cd project
```

You want to track the upstream changes in a `vendor` branch and do
your own work in the `master` branch. Start by renaming the existing
`master` branch to `vendor`:

```
$ git branch -m master vendor
```

This preserves the configuration set up by the `clone` operation:

```
$ git config --get-regexp 'branch.vendor.*'
branch.vendor.remote origin
branch.vendor.merge refs/heads/master
```

And now create your `master` branch:

```
$ git checkout -b master
```

And have at it!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to ensure these are different files, and that your local content is referenced by .gitignore.  Barring that ability, you'll need to exclude your hacks on each commit.